# Meaning of うりこぼる or うりこぶる - EDIT : AUDIO ADDED

Tags: meaning

**EDIT : [Here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0qSxNzp2PUx) is the extract.**

---

I heard the expression うりこぼる or (うりこぶる I'm not sure) in the anime 進撃の巨人 and can't find much info on it.  It's from episode 4 around 10:30, just after マルコ's lines.  The sentence is pronounced by ジャン.

The full sentence is :

> うりこぼらないで言えよ...本音を。

I wonder if it is an idiomatic expression or an abbreviation of one, or something else.

The general idea seems to be "stop lying".

Comment: I believe it's an idiom that, used here, would be something like, "Stop trying to sell us that and tell the truth."

Comment: That's kind of what I was guessing  but I still don't know if it's 売り子ぶる or 売り子ぼる, litteraly "look like a salesman" or "ripping us off like a salesman"

Comment: That audio file (or the source video) is broken. [Here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0qSxNzp2PUx) is my recording. As @Micky answer,   It's definitely お利口ぶらないで.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's お[利口]{りこう}ぶらないで言えよ、本音を。

お利口ぶる means いい子ぶる "to pretend to be a good boy; to act goody-goody"

Comment: Interesting. The Japanese sub file I have says 売り子ぼる・・・. It could be wrong, I guess.

Comment: @Eric Fansubs ?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Yeah. I do like to believe that whoever wrote them at least *understood* what they were writing, though.

Comment: 売り子ぼる doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: @Eric I think the subs fans made for that show have lots of errors, actually.